# In which order do parameters change in ParametersVariation?

Tags: java, anylogic

I am using AnyLogic and doing a ParameterVariation.
I am currently interested in the way AnyLogic changes the parameters.
Lets say I have 3 parameters:

`p_numbers`, `p_zipcode` and `p_floor`

`p_numbers` is set that it starts at 1 and ends at 5 by a range of 1.

`p_zipcode` is set that it starts at 1 and ends at 3 by a range of 1.

`p_floor` is set that it starts at 1 and ends at 4 by a range of 1.

So is there a rule how the parameters get updated after one iteration?

I know that it is possible to print it out in excel which I am currently doing but the experiment is going to run probably until tomorrow so I am just curious.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fixed rule.

Under the hood, OptQuest is making those decisions for you and it accounts for many different factors (max runs, number of replications, number of parallel processors available). They do not publish how this is done so you are stuck with a black-box.

Also note that the sequence will vary between experiments, even if everything stays fixed. NEVER rely on sequence of execution :)

If you ever need to have control over this, you'd need to design a `CustomExperiment` and explicitly tell it how to vary your params for you. But that is not trivial...